# the form of conditional sentence in the indicative mood when expressing future in the past

Tags: past-tense, subjunctive-mood, indirect-speech, future-in-past, indicative

> Any bridge over the river would need to be a very high suspension bridge. Considering the limited technology in those days, building such a bridge seemed impossible. That is, people thought it was impossible until John Roebling, an expert at building suspension bridges, accepted the challenge.
> John proposed the use of steel cables––instead of iron ones––that would be six times stronger than needed to support the bridge. In addition, he planned to build two large stone towers to hold up the bridge’s road and allow people to walk across it. **If his ideas worked, the final result would be the longest, strongest suspension bridge ever built.** John’s ambition inspired people, so construction began in 1869.

In this passage from an High School English Textbook, I'm not sure the conditional sentence in bold letters is in the indicative mood or the in subjunctive mood.
In my opinion the indicative mood was used. In the context John's ideas for the seemingly impossible construction inspired people to start the construction. So the situation in the conditional is not unreal or hypothetical. It was probable enough, though it had been seemed to be impossible.
Another reason for my opinion is that if I say that sentence in the direct speech adding probable John's remark in those days like

*a. John said,"If my ideas work, the final result will be the longest, strongest suspension bridge that has ever been built"*

Then it leads to the same sentence as the quoted conditional sentence like the following.

*b. If his ideas worked, the final result would be the longest, strongest suspension bridge that had ever been built.*

*c. If his ideas worked, the final result would be the longest, strongest suspension bridge ever built.*

Could I say that the quoted conditional sentence c was derived from the sentence b which was also derived form sentence a.? Otherwise, Is the sentence c used in the subjunctive mood?

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you that English does not have a mood system; it was lost in earlier stages of the language. The so-called subjunctive is now regarded as a clause type that is headed by a plain form verb. In your example, the protasis "if his ideas worked" is a preposition phrase functioning as a conditional adjunct, and the apodosis is a declarative content clause.

Comment: The broad definition of 'irrealis' ([Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/irrealis-were-grammar-1691045): 'Defined more broadly, irrealis refers to an event that hasn't occurred (or at least hasn't yet occurred), while realis refers to an event that has occurred.') is situation- rather than syntax-based. It applies with 'If his ideas worked, the final result would be the longest, strongest suspension bridge ever built' because the deictic centre (Roebling or commentators pre-1869) is pre-Brooklyn Bridge, the situation hypothetical.

Comment: Except that there is no irrealis mood in Present-day English. Norquist is referring to 'irrealis were', an untidy relic of an earlier system.

Comment: @BillJ. If English does not have a mood system, how can we distinguish the following sentences a and b in the quoted passage above? 
**a. If his ideas worked, the final result would be the longest and strongest bridge ever built.** (hypothetical condition - like the situation John's doubters were supposing at that time) 
**b. If his ideas worked, the final result would be the longest and strongest bridge ever built.** (factual, probable condition - like the situation John's supporters were supposing)

Comment: I suppose you could use the term 'indicative', but it does no work, so no one bothers to use the term nowadays. As I said above, English does not have an inflectional mood system; it was lost in earlier stages of the language. Mood is mostly marked in English by the modal auxiliaries. The were of "I wish that were true" is an isolated irrealis mood form.

Comment: @BillJ. I think that I've got your point that English does not have the so-called subjunctive by an inflectional mood system.  But, what I'd like to know is how I can **distinguish between the two conditions**(i.e. hypothetical vs. factual)  **the bold quoted sentence in the passage** might be based on. Does it depend on the context and the reader?

Comment: They're not distinguished syntactically, but by context.